# CSS menu hidden over other elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

can you please help about a menu that is hidden behind some other elements in this page:

http://www.monitor-emf.ro/index.php/en/

i think that the slideshow is causing the problem but i can not figure what exactly is the cause. If you expand the menu (Iasi regional division->Iasi) you will see that the bottom of second level drop down is hidden behind main content area! i have tried to set overflow and z-index in these elements without sucess.

Can somebody expert on this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this from the http://www.monitor-emf.ro/t3-assets/css_5eb95.css, line 17.

```
body#bd #ja-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or change it to:

```
body#bd #ja-wrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

If you need the overflow hidden on the width for some other reason.

Comment: doh... you're right! working and answering questions... fixing now